# De qué manera podría tomar los valores de un array de tres en tres Java?

Tags: java

Quisiera añadir valores de tres en tres de un array X, para posteriormente añadirlos a un arraylist Y, de modo que si por ejemplo tengo en mi array X los valores "123456", en el arraylist Y queden dos valores, uno de "123" y otro de "456".

He intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
private ArrayList sort(String text){
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    String currentVal = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        int currentI = i+1;
        if(currentI%3!=0){
            currentVal += chars[i];
        }else{
            values.add(currentVal);
            currentVal = "";
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

Pero de esta manera no funciona correctamente, y me arroja los valores: "12" y "45". Alguien me podría orientar para que este código funcione correctamente?

Comment: ya probaste a aumentar i de tres en tres y leer dentro a variables mediante [i],[i+1] y [i+2] ?

Comment: Lo que puse es un ejemplo. Mi idea es hacerlo de manera dinámica, puesto que los valores no serán siempre 6, pueden ser más. @Ruslan López

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requiere una mínima modificación puesto lo que necesitas es cuando el valor este en la posición `index+1 es multiplo de 3` agréguelo al `values`, ademas de esto para que el próximo `string` que se agregue se agregue sin los valores anteriores debes "limpiar" el `string`:

```
private ArrayList sort(String text){
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
String currentVal = "";
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    currentVal += chars[i]; 
    if((i+1)%3==0){
        values.add(currentVal);
        currentVal = "";
    }
}
return values;
}
```

Recomendación: Cambiar `String currentVal` por un `StringBuilder` para evitar problemas de memoria [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html)

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue sin responderlo, puesto que imprime lo siguiente:
1
2
34
5

Comment: me disculpo habia un error `(i+1)%3!=0` debe ser `(i+1)%3==0`, ya lo corregui, realiza una prueba.

Comment: Ahora sí, quedó perfecto. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Porque no puedas usar la función `substring()`?

```
private ArrayList sort(String text){
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    values.add(text.substring(0,3));
    values.add(text.substring(3));

    return values;
}
```

También no entiendo porque la función se llama "sort", porque eso significa "ordenar". Porque la función no se llama "split" - que significa "partir"?